# Django: Python access to onetone field

Tags: python, django

I have the following code:

```
fixtures = StraightredFixture.objects.select_related().filter(soccerseason=soccerseason,fixturematchday=fixturematchday).order_by('fixturedate')
temp2 = fixtures[0].hometeamscore
```

It works but it is using the "hometeamscore" from the model "StraightredFixture" but I need it from "StraightredFixtureLive".  Could someone help me amend my code accordingly, many thanks, Alan.

The two models are as below:

```
class StraightredFixture(models.Model):
    fixtureid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    home_team = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredTeam', db_column='hometeamid', related_name='home_fixtures')
    away_team = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredTeam', db_column='awayteamid', related_name='away_fixtures')
    fixturedate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    fixturestatus = models.CharField(max_length=24,null=True)
    fixturematchday = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredFixtureMatchday', db_column='fixturematchday')
    spectators = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    hometeamscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    awayteamscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)   

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fixtureid

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'straightred_fixture'

class StraightredFixtureLive(models.Model):
    fixtureid = models.OneToOneField(StraightredFixture, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,)
    hometeamscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    awayteamscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fixtureid

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'straightred_fixturelive'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the related One-to-One field instance and then the instance's `hometeamscore` field:

```
temp = fixtures[0].straightredfixturelive.hometeamscore
#                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I thought I did that but then realised I did NOT change it to lowercase.  Thank you ever so much.  Can't accept answer just yet but will do as soon as I can, many thanks, Alan.